# How to know paging UIScrollView expected page/offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView with pagingEnabled=YES
How to know expected page/offset at the moment when user stop dragging and scrollView start automatically animate to this expected page/offset.
I see a lot of simple examples, where we can know page at the and decelerating - after scroll animation. It's not what I want. I mean expected is before decelerating and animation, at the same moment when user stop dragging or make swipe.

scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset: has really helpful parameter for this - targetContentOffset.

> The expected offset when the scrolling action decelerates to a stop.

But

> This method is not called when the value of the scroll view’s pagingEnabled property is YES.

iOS7 has nice bug with this method and it call independed to pagingEnabled, but we cant use it at early versions of iOS.

Comment: Did you set the `UIScrollViewDelegate`?

Comment: Of course, all the rest scroll view delegate methods call.